# Mobile App UI Performance - RhoMobile Rhodes vs. PhoneGap

Tags: performance, cordova, flicker, rhomobile, rhodes

Has anyone made experiences with both Rhodes and PhoneGap?

I tried building the same "Hello World"-App with both Frameworks for Android, and tested them on a Samsung Galaxy S device running Android 2.3.3.

In both cases, i used HTML5 & jQuery Mobile (in the same version) to design the UI.

The app does nothing but offering a link on the "Home"-Page which uses a slide transition to a second page. The Rhodes app needs longer to startup, but has a very smooth animation when transitioning to the second page. The PhoneGap app flickers and jerks.

Did anyone of you experience a similar behavior? And could you resolve the issues in the PhoneGap version? Could the difference lie in different browser engines / WebViews used by Rhodes / PhoneGap?

Comment: Please, specify the api level or the android version you are using your app.

Comment: I am using Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a good answer, as I'm fairly new to Rhodes and Phonegap myself. What I do know is that RhoMobile uses Motorola's own build of WebKit if you have [RhoElements enabled](http://edgedocs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/rhoelements2-native#enabling-motorola-device-capabilities) or have [added `motorola_browser` as a capability](http://edgedocs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/rhoelements2-native#enabling-motorola-webkit).

If your Rhodes app was using Motorola's Webkit, I suppose it's possible that the custom Webkit build has been optimized for rendering the content generated by Rhodes, with its [EMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMML_%28Motorola%29) and all. This is just speculation, of course.

Phonegap, however, relies on the system's browser and what it offers in terms of performance. AFAIK, it's basically a UIWebView object on iOS.

A really neat bonus of using Motorola's Webkit is you'll have only one browser to work against, across all platforms. (At least in theory, I haven't yet tested how consistent the render engine actually is across platforms.)

To sum up, Rhodes/RhoMobile sounds awesome on paper. I'm just hoping it will live up to my expectetions. Your "Hello world" test could be just a fluke with Phonegap, or it could mean that Motorola's Webkit is indeed performing better. Guess I'll find out sooner or later.

Comment: Hi ximo ... are you still using RhoMobile?  If so, how is it working out for you?